# Custom Product Collection only for discounted product with Layered Navigation in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, layered-navigation

I want to display only discounted price product in specific cms page for magento 1 I have follow this link [http://www.techytalk.info/adding-layered-navigation-custom-controller-action-magento/comment-page-1/] and I have try same thing in Magento 2 but its not working I can able to display only discounted product using this method  `prepareProductCollection($collection)` in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category` but toolbar section display wrong count and left side filter also not display correct count.

Thanks